# Como retorno el valor de Stored-procedure en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

acabo de hacer un Store procedure en sql server. esta es la estructura.

```
USE [AuditoriasDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spFindOrInsertSucursalProveedores]    Script Date: 18/08/2018 01:23:58 p. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFindOrInsertSucursalProveedores] 
    @SucursalID int,
    @ProveedorID int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT proveedorid FROM SucursalProveedores WHERE sucursalid = @SucursalID and proveedorid = @ProveedorID)
         BEGIN
             RETURN(0)  
         END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO SucursalProveedores (SucursalID, ProveedorID) VALUES (@Sucursalid, @ProveedorID)
        END

    SET @Result = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

El codigo como lo llamo.

```
  const string sql = @"[dbo].[spFindOrInsertSucursalProveedores]";

                        var result = conn.Execute(sql, new
                        {
                            SucursalID = Convert.ToInt32(cboSuc.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                            ProveedorID = Convert.ToInt32(cboProv.SelectedValue.ToString())
                        }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

result siempre es -1
```

En la primera secuencia de control, le agregue un return de 0 en caso de existir.
del caso contrario, que agrege el valor, pero al llamarlo en con el framework orm daper este me retorna el valor de -1.
siempre, es decir no me duplica los datos, que ese es el objetivo del sp, pero me retorna siempre -1.
como podria hacer que me retorne 0 en caso de que no ocurra la insercion y que me retorne el valor mayor a 0 cuando este lo haga.
Espero que me ayuden.

gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo prueba hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
USE [AuditoriasDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spFindOrInsertSucursalProveedores]    Script Date: 18/08/2018 01:23:58 p. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFindOrInsertSucursalProveedores] 
    @SucursalID INT,
    @ProveedorID INT,
    @Result INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT proveedorid FROM SucursalProveedores WHERE sucursalid = @SucursalID and proveedorid = @ProveedorID)
         BEGIN
             SET @Result = 0; 
         END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO SucursalProveedores (SucursalID, ProveedorID) VALUES (@Sucursalid, @ProveedorID)
            SET @Result = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        END
END
```

Comment: la declaracion de @Result no hay problema que lo indique dentro del alter procedure?

Comment: Como quieras pero tendrás que hacer un select @Result antes del ultimo end para que te envié el valor.